# Powershell - Get-Content from remote JPG specific line

Tags: windows, powershell, system-administration

So basically I have a local .jpg file that I can successfully pull strings from and output to PowerShell by doing the following:

```
(Get-Content file.jpg)[4]
```

Which prints the fourth line of code. The problem is I want to pull the same line from the .jpg once its  hosted on a webserver.

I've tried everything I can think of however I can't seem to pull the specific data from the .jpg when it's sitting on a webserver.

I thought this would work but still no luck:

```
$JPG=$web.DownloadString("http://boeprox.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/capture_thumb1.jpg")
(Get-Content $JPG)[4]
```

Before anyone gets wise and suggest saving the file locally and doing it that is not an option, file needs to stay on remote server and not touch disk.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Get-Content` is to get the contents of a file. You already have them in a string. Something might be wrong with this but it works to some extent ``($web.DownloadString("http://boeprox.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/capture_thumb1.jpg") -split "`r")[4]``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have an encoding issue to deal with but the root of your issue is that `Get-Content` returns and array of strings. `DownloadString` is returning just that, a string.

Knowing that i converted the return into and array of strings

```
($web.DownloadString("http://boeprox.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/capture_thumb1‌​.jpg") -split "`r")
```

I had originally used  `` "`r`n" `` for the split but it was not working. So now I was able to get the 5th line as you were

```
($web.DownloadString("http://boeprox.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/capture_thumb1‌​.jpg") -split "`r")[4]
```

However it just looked like this.

```
ÊÃ#Œ©|•ð×ÇÚ‡ü#¥i’üCºðÝí­åôÓ˜ô(õ0Í¹bº€§ärcóÎÜŒ×øƒã­]Ô|'5§ÄST]7QºšîfÓRÍí„—†
Cq  UÈ.„7—ólpqØ²sò¶í¯OøüDóYZö_yö|fð‹YÉ¨'Å›´‰¶Ip5g1#qÁ|à™x'ø‡¨§éÿ üªLm´Ï‹6
“2íõW•‚­…$àw=+ä¿…¿ ðþâ‹+Ï:Ÿ†ôýOUi%°‡FP“QY´¶üa—j‚~R7rH®,|dø´úÝ·Šn~Î,Õã
µŠ8ÌjAVò‚ív7nä’iÇ‡£)8©mývÍœRm_y÷Tß|hOÚþ/i°âW€ùš³.%B¡ÉûÊHÈê23SÙügðmõÌVV_ìn
.&RÑC¦ï$€rª9# œŽÀ×Ã²|~ø˜ÂVR°Šk«ƒww2iñº›td;î<˜ÇÊ¹9'5€¿¼`ºÞ›â?íEmCI´66r½¼l
Ü‡YR0À  rÕk†Õµ—åþD¼âÛ#ïØ¾<|<·—ñ“H}ªY¶êäí©8<RÚüvøyu4vÖ¿´™æ•‚GZ³;»@9'ØWÂ7
_¾!\Á
```

Comment: Champion! You saved me.

Comment: @shadowmoses Dont suppose you could tell me how that blob of text is useful to you?

Comment: It's the least I could do after that (I was stuck playing with it for hours). So what I am researching at the moment is the usage of stenography, the blob of text is hashed with a value only the requester knows.

Answer (score 0):

Does this get what you're looking for?  To be honest, I've never heard of using Get-Content on anything besides text files but you learn something new every day :)

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://boeprox.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/capture_thumb1.jpg').Content[4]
```

Comment: For this to work you need to do something else with the data. `.Content` in this case is just a `System.Byte[]` object. I suppose you could convert it back to a string.

Comment: I thought so but I still don't get using Get-Content to read the contents of a binary file.

Comment: Thanks for the input adbertram, Unfortunately using the Invoke on it's own was not cutting it, Matt's suggestion worked like a charm with the addition of substring since the true line position actually got modified after uploading it to the webserver (No idea).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SysInternals [strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439.aspx) utility to extract strings from binary files e.g.

```
(strings -q ..\Pictures\foo.png)[3]
```

BTW is there any reason you can't store it to a temp file?  Is the problem that you don't have write privileges?

Comment: Strings is good, did not know strings can invoke http requests (If that's what you meant). I was originally storing to temp file no problem, but I guess i have obsessive compulsive disorder and wanted to see how far I could push the envelope so to speak. On-the-fly is always much sexier no?

Comment: Up to a point, yes. :-)  And no, strings.exe doesn't do http requests. It is just a handy command line utility to extract strings from binary files.

Comment: Cool, yeah I use strings all the time both on deb/arch and Windows it's good. It's a wonder Powershell doesn't have a native alternative besides "Select-String".